# How do I create a mutable string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, string, mutable

I am using the `# frozen_string_literal: true` magic comment that RuboCop enforces by default, and I can't append something to a string:

```rb
string = 'hello'

string << ' world'
```

because it errors out with:

> can't modify frozen String (RuntimeError)

Comment: Why do you turn on frozen strings when you don't want your strings to be frozen?

Comment: Because, as mentioned, it's enforced by default by RuboCop, and I tend to trust them, and because I do want some strings to be immutable.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You add a `+` before the string like:

```rb
string = +'hello'

string << ' world'

puts(string)
```

> hello world

Comment: Backwards compatible alternatives: `String.new('hello')` or `'hello'.dup`

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `+=`:

```rb
s = 'H'
s += 'ello
```

> => "Hello"

Answer (score 3):

`frozen_string_literal` is for string literal. To create a mutable String instance, use `String#new` or prepend a `+` to the string literal.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true
'foo'.frozen? # => true
String.new.frozen? # => false
(+'foo').frozen? # => false
```

Comment: What does this answer add different from [this anwer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57795069/865175) and [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57795068/how-do-i-create-a-mutable-string-in-ruby/59132415#comment102024591_57795069)?

Comment: 1) I usually don't read all comments of all other answers, so do some people. 2) My answer is unique to other answers in this thread.

Answer (score 0):

When `# frozen_string_literal: true` is enabled, you **cannot** 'mutate' any strings.

Want proof?
With the following script...

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: true

str = 'hello'
str << ' world'
```

you will get the following error...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
frozen_strings.rb:4:in `<main>': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
```

'Mutate' means *change the value of the object*.
Therefore, your example fails because `<<` mutates strings and it is mutating your string `string` since you are using the `<<` operator.

Want proof?
Go into irb!
Enter the follow:

```rb
str = 'hello' # => 'hello'
obj_id1 = str.object_id # => some number, ex: 12345
str << ' world' # => 'hello world'
obj_id2 = str.object_id # => some number, ex: 12345
obj_id1 == obj_id2 # this should return true, proving that you mutated the object
```

However, you can get around this by using `str += ' world'`.
Why? Because `+=` is a shorthand reassignment. Instead of mutating, `+=` creates a brand new string (with a brand new object_id) and stores it under the same variable name (in this case, str).

Want Proof? Check it out in irb!

```rb
str = 'hello' # => 'hello'
obj_id1 = str.object_id # => some number, ex: 12345
str += ' world' # => ' world'
obj_id2 = str.object_id # => some other number, ex: 356456345
obj_id1 == obj_id2 # => this returns false!
```

Let me know if this helped!

Comment: When `# frozen_string_literal: true` is enabled, you **can** 'mutate' a string by using `string << 'string'` instead of `string += 'string'` that you mentioned.

Comment: This code gave me an error...
```ruby
# frozen_string_literal: true

str = 'hello'
str << ' world'

```
```
Traceback (most recent call last):
frozen_strings.rb:4:in `<main>': can't modify frozen String (FrozenError)
```

Comment: And besides, that example proves that you cannot mutate strings while `# frozen_string_literal: true` is enabled, but in your first comment you're asserting that you can.

Comment: I didn't want to come up as rude. But your last reply is still incorrect. Again, you can mutate strings, even when `frozen_string_literal` is set to `true`, if you initialize it using `= +`, and **not** simply `=`.